# R: Get the last entry from previous group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like this:

```
Group Year Month Mean_Price
  A    2013  6      200
  A    2013  6      200
  A    2014  2      100  
  A    2014  2      100
  B    2014  1      130
```

I want to add another column which gets the last entry from the group above, like this:

```
Group Year Month Mean_Price  Last_Mean_price
  A    2013  6      200           x
  A    2013  6      200           x
  A    2014  2      100         200 
  A    2014  2      100         200  ---This is where I am facing problem as doing dplyr + lag is just getting the last row entry and not the entry of th *last group's* last row.
  B    2014  1      130           x
  B    2014  4      140         130
```

All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

I had asked a related question here: [Get the (t-1) data within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286743/get-the-t-1-data-within-groups?noredirect=1#comment50574644_31286743)
But then I wasn't grouping by years and months

Comment: Can you show your code and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

This may be one way to go. I am not sure how you want to group your data. Here, I chose to group your data with `GROUP`, `Year`, and `Month`. First, I want to create a vector with all last elements from each group, which is `foo`.

```
group_by(mydf, Group, Year, Month) %>%
summarize(whatever = last(Mean_Price)) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(whatever) %>%
unlist -> foo

# whatever1 whatever2 whatever3 whatever4 
# 200       100       130       140
```

Second, I arranged `foo` for our later process. Basically, I added `x` in the first position and deleted the last element in `foo`.

```
### Arrange a vector 
foo <- c("x", foo[-length(foo)])
```

Third, I added row numbers for each group in `mydf` using `mutate()`. Then, I relaxed all numbers but 1 with x.

```
group_by(mydf, Group, Year, Month) %>%
mutate(ind = row_number(),
       ind = replace(ind, which(row_number(ind) != 1), "x")) -> temp
```

Finally, I identified rows which have 1 in `ind` and assigned the vector, `foo` to the rows.

```
temp$ind[temp$ind == 1] <- foo
temp

#   Group  Year Month Mean_Price   ind
#  (fctr) (int) (int)      (int) (chr)
#1      A  2013     6        200     x
#2      A  2013     6        200     x
#3      A  2014     2        100   200
#4      A  2014     2        100     x
#5      B  2014     1        130   100
#6      B  2014     4        140   130
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L), Month = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L), Mean_Price = c(200L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 130L, 140L)), .Names = c("Group", "Year", "Month", 
"Mean_Price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for yur answer.. However mutate(ind = row_number().... does'nt work as it is expecting an arguement in row_number and throwing an error 
`Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @UD1989 Could you use `mydf` above and test the code? Otherwise, could you please upload a part of your real data using `dput()`?

Comment: @UD1989 On my side, `mutate(ind = row_number()...` is working. If necessary, you can fill in the bracket part with `Mean_Price`.